# How to print unicode string in PHP

Tags: php

I have this small script:

```
<?
header('Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=utf-8');
$s="L\u00e1szl\u00f3 M\u00e1rton";
echo $s;
?>
```

The browser displays "L\u00e1szl\u00f3 M\u00e1rton"

and it should display László Márton.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you have to understand the difference between server, browser and javascript.

To answer your question "How to print unicode string in PHP" is simple: just print it:

```
echo "László Márton";
```

But it seems you want to print Javascript-encoded sequence. OK. But you need to print well formed javascript then.

Comment: @Pentium how to do what? Javascript code? Just write it. I have no idea what javascript code you want. But string "László Márton" doesn't looks like javascript code

Comment: This is from a JSON response, I don't have javascript, only PHP or Java.

Comment: @Pentium it is not JSON response either. You have to learn how to encode json responses properly. And I don't have java, only PHP or Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at the [mbstring](https://www.php.net/mbstring) library in PHP?

[This page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-output-handler.php) shows you some basic multibyte output string handling.

Also, as pointed out in another answer, your charset should be `utf-8`

Comment: It doesn't help. I added mb_http_output("UTF-8");
ob_start("mb_output_handler"); but I get no change.

Answer (score 0):

try using charset=utf-8 instead of utf8

here's a helpful resource for php charset problems:
http://www.phpwact.org/php/i18n/charsets